# Gunicorn limit server performance

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, wsgi, flask-socketio

I have developed a Flask app and it works pretty well in the development stage, but when I set up the production process with Gunicorn, the performance decreased a lot.

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) to make production with Gunicorn.

My app uses socket-io, so the server catch requests at realtime in development mode as designed, but with Gunicorn the requests even delayed a lot or doesn't reach the server at all.

I had run Gunicorn in different ways, changed workers, threads, and app as following.

```
sudo gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --workers 2 wsgi:app
sudo gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --workers 2 app:app

sudo gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --workers 3 --threads 3 wsgi:app
sudo gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --workers 3 --threads 3 app:app

sudo gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --workers 8 --threads 4 wsgi:app
sudo gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --workers 8 --threads 4 app:app
```

my `wsgi.py`:

```
from app import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

my `app.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
    
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
app.url_map.strict_slashes = False
socketio = SocketIO(app)

from control.control import *
from video_streaming import video_streaming_blueprint
app.register_blueprint(video_streaming_blueprint)

def disable_logs(app, disable):
    import logging
    log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
    log.disabled = disable
    app.logger.disabled = disable

if __name__ == '__main__':
    disable_logs(app=app, disable=True)
    socketio.run(app=app, host='0.0.0.0', debug=False)
```

- **The server runs on a local machine.**

Answer (score 0):

The Flask-SocketIO package has detailed [deployment instructions](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#deployment).

To have good performance you need to add WebSocket to your server. For this you are going to have to use an asynchronous worker for gunicorn, either gevent or eventlet.

Using more than one worker is possible, but often not necessary as the async workers handle their own concurency. If you do want to use multiple workers, then you need to add a load balancer such as nginx and a message queue such as redis or rabbitmq.